# How to check if a variable value is increasing or decreasing and show the number with what it increased or decreased

Tags: javascript

This is a dumb question, And I can't believe I asked for a solution, Well now that I am pretty good I answered it. So, Firstly I create the variable `number` then I add two properties to it's prototype called `oldValue` and `randomize` then I set `randomize` to a random decimal number between `0` and `1` using `Math.random()`, I store the value of the `number` variable before any further changes, In the property I added to the prototype called `oldValue`, After that I check if the `randomize` is less than `0.5` or more than `0.5` if less then I decrement a random number between `50-100` else I increment with a number between `50-100`, At last I `console.log()` the changes.

```js
let number = 0;
number.__proto__.oldValue = number;
number.__proto__.randomize = 0;
let interval = setInterval(() => {
    number.__proto__.randomize = Math.random();
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
    number.__proto__.oldValue = number;
    if (number.randomize > 0.5) number += randomNumber;
    else number -= randomNumber;
    console.log((number - number.oldValue) < 0 ? `decrement: ${number} ${number.oldValue}` : `increment: ${number} ${number.oldValue}`);
}, 100)
```

Comment: just add a console.log within the function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the delta in a variable. Additionally, to generate a random boolean, you only need to check if `Math.random()` is greater than `0.5`.

```js
var number = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  let delta = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) * (Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1);
  console.log('Delta:', delta);
  number += delta;
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating random number you can store it. `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`

Like this:

```js
var number = 0;
        var randomize = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
            randomize = 0;
            randomize += Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            if (randomize > 50) {
                let newRandomise = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                number += newRandomise

                console.log("increased by", newRandomise)
            }
            else {
                console.log("deccreased by", randomize)
                number -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
            }
        }, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some `console.log` s that will help you

```js
var number = 0;
var randomize = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    randomize = 0;
    randomize += Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    if (randomize > 50) {
        const incrementer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        console.log('Increased by', incrementer);
        number += incrementer;
    }
    else {
        const decrementer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        console.log('Decreased by', decrementer);
        number -= decrementer;
    }
}, 100)
```